# What does " assuming responsibility " mean?

Tags: collocations

I think you assume responsibility when you think  someone who is on-duty does not  behave in responsible way so you do the job without authorization.

Are they used also in the following senses?

> 1.The state or fact of having a duty to deal with something or of having control over someone:
>
> > Women bear children and take responsibility for childcare
>
> 2.The state or fact of being accountable or to blame for something:
>
> > The group has claimed responsibility for a string of murders

Comment: That is not really what "assume responsibility" means.  It has nothing to do with not having authorization, or with thinking that someone else is not being responsible.  It just means "to accept the duty of doing something."

Comment: Agreed. You can assume responsibility when somebody gives it to you, or you can take responsibility on your own initiative.

Comment: How about " to take up" , do you think its meaning şmply something different than to taken on responsibility and to assume responsibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming responsibility, often means taking control of a situation, group, establishment, ect.

Example: *The politician assumed responsibility for his Party.*

It is also commonly used to say being responsible for your own actions, your children's actions, or something else. (Your second point)

Example: *The boy decided he should assume responsibility for his own actions.* -- Normally you would write "be responsible" instead of "assume responsibility" here, but both are OK.

Another way it is used, is to say that you are taking care of something.

Example: *Our Neighbour was on holiday, so we assumed responsibility for her cat.*

> I think you assume responsibility when you think someone who is on-duty does not behave in responsible way so you do the job without authorization.

This could be a possible reason for assuming responsibility, but it could be for other reasons. For example: To help out, To get a pay rise, because you want to be in control ect.

Answer (score 1):

To assume responsibility mean to *take on* responsibility. 
You could use **assume** in both contexts that you described. This is the definition of assume (in that context)

Take on (take) or begin to have (power or responsibility).

> Women bear children and *take on* responsibility for childcare
>
> Women bear children and **assume** responsibility for childcare

Or;

> The group has *taken on* responsibility for a string of murders
>
> The group has **assumed** responsibility for a string of murders

[here is the definition of assume (look at the second)](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=assume&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: How about " to take up" , do you think its meaning şmply something different than to taken on  responsibility and to assume responsibility.?

Comment: No, I don't think that would work very well instead of, take on. This is the dictionary definition of take on. To begin to perform or deal with.  But 'take up' most of the time means literately to grab or take something. Often times it will mean something similar to 'take on' but it sounds wrong in that context  in my opinion.

Comment: try looking each phrase up.